# SQL Comma separated values with COALESCE

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

My query:

```
DECLARE @Groups VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @Groups = COALESCE(@Groups + ',', '') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GroupID)
FROM  
    [dbo].[tblGroups]

PRINT @Groups
```

This returns

```
            2345,6543,7854
```

I want the `@Groups` to return '2345','6543','7854', since I need to use `@Groups` in another query:

```
SELECT *   
FROM MyTable
WHERE GROUP_ID IN (@Groups)
```

I get an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2345,6543,7854' to data type int.

Currently, I am testing the second query in SQL Server and getting this error, but actually I have to run the second query in teradata and the query 1 results `@Groups` from SQL Server have to be passed). I think if I am able to return `@Groups` as '2345','6543','7854', it should solve my problem.

Please guide how to achieve this

Comment: That's probably not going to work anyway. Wouldn't it be better to create a subquery to retrieve the data from tbGoups

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a table variable instead?

```
DECLARE @Groups TABLE (Groups VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Groups
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GroupID)
FROM [dbo].[tblGroups]

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE GROUP_ID IN (SELECT *
                   FROM @Groups)
```

*********************** **EDIT** ***********************

```
DECLARE @Groups VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Groups = COALESCE(@Groups + ',', '''') + CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), GroupID) + ''''
FROM  
    [dbo].[tblGroups]

PRINT @Groups
```

**** **EDIT** ****

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (GroupID INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab
VALUES (2345),(6543),(7854)
DECLARE @Groups VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Groups = COALESCE(@Groups + ',', '') +''''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GroupID) + ''''
FROM @Tab
SELECT @Groups
```

Results:

```
'2345','6543','7854'
```

Comment: That is not the same logic as OP posted, since it merely duplicates the rows in tblGroups in your table variable rather than using an unsupported trick for concatenating strings using aggregation. And more importantly, why? As @Simon suggests, the better approach is to a subquery (or join) directly - no duplication needed.

Comment: Using logic that works > Using unsupported trick... IMO... It was the quickest write up and first thing that came to my mind when I saw OP was trying to use a variable. Simon made that comment before I posted my answer.. I'll leave that answer for him.

Comment: The problem is that that query 1 is in SQL server and query 2 is going to be in Teradata. @Groups will be passed to Teradata as a variable through a process. So can't use subquery or table variable.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question if this helps understanding my problem- How can this query return a comma separated values? Result doesn't have to be in a variable     
     SELECT Distinct GroupID
     FROM [dbo].[tblGroups]

Comment: @bjones, I tried that already. Doesn't give quotes correctly with each number

Comment: @SilverFish, minor edit again along with my results.

Comment: @bjones, when I am using this query in next query, I'm still getting same error-Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''2345','6543','7854'' to data type int. Not sure what to do?

Comment: @SilverFish, I posted that a little premature. Check again... As for the error, the single quotes will not fix that. Like I initially suggested, when using `IN` you will need a table variable or some other technique. It's trying to convert the literal string - '2345','6543','7854' - to an integer, which isn't going to happen.

Comment: @bjones, I agree with you. I cannot use a nested query, CTE, or table variable since I have to go across servers. Is there any other way I could get results in a comma delimited string such as '2345','6543','7854' ? Since variable is not working, I guess I can try a SELECT query or something

Comment: @bjones, I figured out how the query 2 will work in sql server, but still need to figure out how to make it work in Teradata. Sql version:     SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(cast(GROUP_ID as varchar(5)),@Groups) > 0